# jQuery Plugin Twice In One HTML Page

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I've put together a script which creates [this](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/testing.php) image gallery page. I'm using 'fancyBox' to create the slideshow and a jquery demo which I've adapted to provide the deletion functionality.

The problem I have is that they both need to use `jquery-1.7.2.min.js` shown in this part of my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/lib/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

This causes a conflict, and I can only run the page without errors, if only one is included.

I'm really very new to jQuery and I'm not even sure whether it is possible. But could someone perhaps tell me please is it possible to run the two together and how I may go about doing this.

Many thanks and regards

Answer (score 1):

You don't need both. It'll run fine using just one of them. It doesn't matter which you remove.

Comment: Hi @Polyomial, many thanks for taking the time to reply. Unfortunately, if I take away one, the functionality that is linked with it is also removed e.g. if I delete the 'fancyBox' link, I can no longer use the 'fancyBox' functionality. Kind regards

Comment: Both `fancybox/lib/jquery-1.7.2.min.js` and `js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js` should be exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery is a library that is used to simplify the work of javascript programming, so, you only need to included it once, before all the scripts that depend on it!

**Using your code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path_to_fancybox_script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path_to_another_script.js"></script>
```

You should read a bit about Jquery from their website: http://jquery.com/

Since you are new to it, you can also learn about it: http://www.learningjquery.com/

Comment: Hi @Zuul, I really do appreciate your reply, and it took me a while to get my head around it, apologies! But after some testing, I've found that, as you and @Polyomial said originally, the problem isn't with the two sets of `jquery-1.7.2.min.js` but it's a conflict between the 'fancybox' and the `jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js`. Could you possibly tell me please is there a way around this? Kind regards